# Is there at least one sequence of this form for which it is proven that it has an infinite number of primes as its values?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> Is there at least one sequence of the form $a^n+b$ where $a \in \mathbb N$ and $b \in \mathbb Z$ for which we know that it contains an infinite number of prime numbers as its values?
>
> If we do not know about at least one sequence of this form that it contains an infinite number of primes for some concrete $a$ and $b$ are there some conjectures/arguments/heuristics that show/suggest that there must exist at least one such sequence?

Comment: AFAIK, no (that's to the first question).

Comment: Relevant: generalized [Dickson's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_conjecture) and [Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture).